# How to convert special characters in HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding

Im looking to convert special characters like smart quotes to HTML entities but without converting other HTML markup because I need HTML markup to work.
For example, convert `<div>NVH “noise”</div>` to  `<div>NVH &ldquo;noise&rdquo; issues<div>`

Its strange that if I log this on my local environment I get “noise” with smartquotes but on server I got ?noise?. My local runs LAMP with php56. server ran 54 and 55. I upgraded to 56 still no luck. I think either something in php configuration or among other things. Same exact code.

Comment: call php code for example htmlspecialchars within the `<div>` tags, so like `<div><?php echo htmlspeciallchars($yourhtml) ?></div>`

Comment: @NicolásCarlo that wont work. its a long string including html markup

Comment: AFAIK, there's no built in way to do this. You get stuff added to frameworks, so if you're using a framework, instead of plain PHP then you may want to look into its docs.

Answer (score 0):

For only one translation of the smart quotes, or for some characters and not others, `str_replace` is probably the only way to go:

```
$string = str_replace(array('“','”'), array('&ldquo;','&rdquo;'), $string);
```

Comment: I wanna be able to cover other special characters too so this wont work.

Comment: Yes it will.  If you want it piecemeal this is about the only option.  Just build  $needle and $haystack arrays with the chars you want.

Comment: Its strange that if I log this on my local environment I get “noise” but on server I got ?noise?. My local runs LAMP with php56. server ran 54 and 55. I upgraded to 56 still no luck. I think either something in php configuration or among other things. Same exact code.

Answer (score -1):

Try php htmlspecialchars method

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;     
?>
```