# passing quotes through url PHP

Tags: php, get

I'm passing ProductName through a URL and 2 of the names have single quotation marks in them (which is causing the buttons to not work) is there any work around for this? I've tried playing with htmlentities() but that's not fixing the issue. I get the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error when I try clicking on a Product that has a quote in it's name.

```
    <?php

$search = $_GET['search'];

require 'db/connect.php';


$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductSearch = '$search'");
if($result->num_rows){
echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">';
echo '<tr><td></td><td><u>Product Name</u></td><td><u>Price</u></td><td><u>Wisconsin Artisans</u></td></tr>';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $ProductId    = $row['ProductId'];
    $ProductImage = htmlentities($row['ProductImage'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $ProductName  = $row['ProductName'];
    $ProductPrice = $row['ProductPrice'];
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="productpage.php?productid=', $row['ProductId'],'"><img height="80px" width="80px "src="', $row['ProductImage'] ,'"/></a></td>';
echo '<td><a id="productlink" href="productpage.php?productid=', $row['ProductId'],'">', $row['ProductName'], '</a></td>';
echo '<td> $', $row['ProductPrice'], '</td>';
echo '<td> ', $row['ProductVendor'], '</td>';
//echo '<td><input type=button onClick="location.href=\'cart.php?ProductId=', $row['ProductId'], '\'" value=\'Add to Cart\' id="addtocart"></td></tr>';
echo '<td><input type=button onClick="location.href=\'cart.php?ProductId=', $ProductId, '&ProductName=', $ProductName, '&ProductPrice=', $ProductPrice, '&ProductQty=1\'" value=\'Add to Cart\' id="addtocart"></td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
$result->free();

}
else{

    echo '<h3 style="color:black;">No products here just yet, but there will be soon!</h3>';

}
?>
```

Comment: You can create your own function to convert special chars into others, for example, single quote into ";sq;" or something like that (use your imagination).

Comment: How would I go about that Jose? I'm kind of learning as I go...

Comment: With JavaScript  = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript

Comment: With PHP = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885466/how-to-convert-special-characters-in-html-using-php

Comment: Why do you set all the variables like `$ProductName`, but you don't use them in the `echo` statements?

Comment: You are in risk of mysql injection attack with the code you use I advise you to make something more secure than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This changing this 'location.href=\'cart.php?ProductId=', $ProductId, '&ProductName=', $ProductName, '&ProductPrice=', $ProductPrice, '&ProductQty=1\'"

To this: location.href=\'cart.php?ProductId='. $ProductId .'&ProductName='. $ProductName .'&ProductPrice='. $ProductPrice .'&ProductQty=1\'"

Also try using heredoc for multiline strings and use the curly braces to render variable values, you won't have problems with quitation:

```
echo <<<END
multi
line
string
variable={$var}
awesome!
END;
```

see https://php.net/language.types.string

Answer (score 0):

```
$ProductImage = htmlentities($row['ProductImage'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
...
echo '....', $row['ProductImage'],'">....
```

You already converted both double and single quotes to their HTML entities, but then you don't use the variable in which you did so.  You should be using `$ProductImage` rather than `$row['ProductImage']` in your echo.

Comment: Should add a note about SQL injections as well. `$search = $_GET['search']; $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductSearch = '$search'");`

Comment: oh.... Woops haha, I haven't had any trouble running it with comas until now! I replaced all the comas with periods, but I'm still getting an error. It's only with products that have single quotes in the ProductName.

Comment: You can replace the single quotes with the HTML entity: `$str = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $str);`

Comment: `echo` allows multiple arguments, separated with comma.

Comment: @developerwjk It's better to use `htmlentities()` to perform your substitutions.

Comment: @Barmar he's supposeldy already running htmlentities with ent_quotes....lol, I see the problem now. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
echo '<td><input type=button onClick="location.href=\'cart.php?ProductId=', $ProductId, '&ProductName=', $ProductName, '&ProductPrice=', $ProductPrice, '&ProductQty=1\'" value=\'Add to Cart\' id="addtocart"></td></tr>';
```

to:

```
echo '<td><input type=button onClick="location.href=\'cart.php?ProductId=', $ProductId, '&ProductName=', urlencode($ProductName), '&ProductPrice=', $ProductPrice, '&ProductQty=1\'" value=\'Add to Cart\' id="addtocart"></td></tr>';
```

`urlencode()` will encode the product name correctly so it can be put in a URL. This will convert quote characters to `%39`.

Comment: That worked like a charm! How do I un encode it afterwords? I've passed it to the cart, but now It's displaying as &#039;

Comment: That's coming from calling `htmlentities()` on the parameter. You should only do that when you're displaying something in HTML, not using it in PHP code.